# Striving to understand Spring MVC model and specific controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have encountered the following code in a Spring-based Java application.

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/plants/form")
public String form(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("plant", new Plant());
    return "plants/create";
}
```

I have several questions regarding this snippet.

1. I know that `form` method is called for requests to `/plants/form`,
   but I would like to know which method invokes `form` and passes arguments to it?
2. To me, it seems that a model is like a database.  So, it looks like
   `model.addAttribute("plant", new Plant());` creates a `Plant`
   instance and makes it accessible in a model under the name **plant**.
   Thus, an attribute of a model seems to be
   something like a `field` in DB. **What is the exact meaning of
   an attribute of a model?**
3. What is `value` in `@RequestMapping(value="/plants/form")` and what
   is the difference between aforementioned notation and 
   `@RequestMapping("/plants/form")`?
4. Consider this incomplete snippet of HTML:

   ```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" th:object="${plant}" th:method="post" th:action="@{/plants}">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
           <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"></input>
       </div>
   </form>
   ```

   What is the meaning of `$, *, @` in `"${plant}"`,`"*{name}"` and
   `"@{/plants}"`. It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If I understand your question correctly, then Spring MVC [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) is responsible for routing request to your handler method based on configured `HandlerMapping`/`HandlerAdapter`.

2) Model is M in MVC, it has nothing in common with relational database. Rather consider it as a `Map` of `String` keys to `Object` values. Spring MVC model attributes are stored in **request scope** under the hood.

3) There is no difference, `value` is the attribute of `@RequestMapping` annotation. When you want to pass a single `value` argument and no other arguments, then it is possible to omit `value` by convention.

4) These are tags and attributes of Thymeleaf *Standard* and *SpringStandard* dialects. More information [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html).